# Procedure showing one record using TEXT_IO

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have procedure in oracle forms 11g in which select records and write into text file. I have 780 records through execute select statement but in text file showing only one record

**CODE:**

```
PROCEDURE list_files IS
out_file text_io.file_type;
v_name_of_files VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
  for c in
  (
    select filename from tab1 
    WHERE filename NOT IN (select distinct filename from tab2)
    order by filename
)
loop
    v_name_of_files := c.filename;
end loop;

out_file := text_io.fopen('C:log.txt', 'w');

text_io.put_line(out_file,'List of files uploaded failed : ');

TEXT_IO.new_line(out_file);

text_io.put_line(out_file,v_name_of_files);

text_io.fclose(out_file);

END;
```

I am using oracle database 11g
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to output the names of the 780 failed files? At the moment your code is executing a loop which overwrites `v_name_of_files` 779 times and then outputs the last entry from `tab1`. You need to change your loop so it calls the file output.

```
PROCEDURE list_files IS

  out_file text_io.file_type;

BEGIN

  out_file := text_io.fopen('C:log.txt', 'w');

  text_io.put_line(out_file,'List of files uploaded failed : ');

  for c in
  (
    select filename from tab1 
    WHERE filename NOT IN (select distinct filename from tab2)
    order by filename
  )
  loop
     text_io.put_line(out_file,c.filename);  
  end loop;

  text_io.fclose(out_file);

END;
```